# Deployment target on Appstore

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I believe the current way the "deployment target" (in Xcode) works has the following functionality in relation with the Appstore:

1. Let's say I've published a version of the app that had the deployment target set to an older version of iOS.
2. Now I am releasing a new version of the same app that has the
   deployment target set to the latest iOS version.

**I expect users
    with older iOS versions to see the app when they search for it in the Appstore (even though they
    will see an older version of the app).**

Please confirm/infirm this and if you can please also point me to the accurate documentation.

I already checked this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

Comment: The end of your 2nd paragraph makes no sense. Please fix the missing words and grammar.

Comment: Try searching first... then read Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html